# Why am I getting a "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'lapcount'" when asking for user input?

Tags: python, python-3.7

making a lap timer which needs to prompt for lap times until the user enters a lap time of x. User input needs to be a float as it will likely contain times including decimal points. I understand that an input can only pass 1 argument but I can not think of another way to do this.

tried using both for and while loops.

```
#Enhanced laptimer w/ list

laps=[]
lapcount=0

while True:
    lapcount=+1
    result=float(input("Enter lap time for lap {}. (push x to end): ", format.lapcount))
    if result == x:
        break
    laps.append(result)

laps.sort()

print("Fastest lap was", laps[0])
print("Slowest lap was", laps[-1])
print("Average lap was", sum(laps)/len(laps))
```

I expect the output to look like this :
Enter lap time 1 ("x" to end): 23.4
Enter lap time 2 ("x" to end): 25.1
Enter lap time 3 ("x" to end): 27.3
Enter lap time 4 ("x" to end): 22.0
Enter lap time 5 ("x" to end): x
Fastest Lap Time: 22.0
Slowest Lap Time: 27.3
Average Lap Time: 24.45

Instead I get this exception:
    result=input("Enter lap time for lap", lapcount, ". (push x to end): ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
result = float(input("Enter lap time for lap %s (push x to end): " % lapcount))
```

Comment: Have updated the question to include string formatting but gives me a new exception (included in the new question). I tried using the % format but it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: @Madekai The thing you tried isn't the same as my code!

Comment: I can see where I stuffed up. Works now. Thank you for your help.